# ng-repeat not displaying keys orderBy correctly

Tags: json, angularjs, indexing, key, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object that has differently named keys and each key has it's own string array as shown below.  However, i cannot orderBy using an ng-repeat the way i want.  The way i want to do it

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in $scope.myModel | orderBy: key"
```

I realize this is because ng-repeat does not allow for ordering via a key and that i will have to have a specifically named key that doesn't change and is repeated in order to do it.      Is there anyway i can properly sort the JSon object i'm displaying via the ng-repeat?
 What i want it to look like is this:

```
10/14/2015 1:30:00 PM: Array[14]
10/14/2015 9:30:00 AM: Array[14]
10/5/2015 9:30:00 PM: Array[14]
10/6/2015 9:30:00 PM: Array[14]
10/7/2015 9:30:00 PM: Array[14]
```

What it looks like when i display it with

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in $scope.myModel"

10/5/2015 9:30:00 PM: Array[14]
10/6/2015 9:30:00 PM: Array[14]
10/7/2015 9:30:00 PM: Array[14]
10/14/2015 1:30:00 PM: Array[14]
10/14/2015 9:30:00 AM: Array[14]
```

Comment: change to ng-repeat="(key, value) in myModel | orderBy: key"
Remove the $scope

Comment: That causes the screen to not display anything since myModel is no longer in scope.

Comment: Since we cannot see your code, so better to check the console for exact error but sure you don't need that $scope in repeat

Comment: There is no error in the console...it simply doesn't display since it's not in scope. The model, for AngularJS, is required to be in proper scope to be displayed.  I don't really think this is the issue here...i'm fairly certain it's the way my keys are all named something different. Is there a way to name them differently but still retain the data?

Answer (score 0):

The filter `orderBy: key` is here useless, as your input is an object. You can't have a guarantee on the order in an object. From `orderBy` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

> Orders a specified **array** by the expression predicate.

You have to transform `$scope.myModel` to an array if you want a guaranteed order.

Comment: Sure, but any suggestions for a possible workaround other than a custom filter?

Comment: You could by example push the values, or the couples `{key: value}`, of `$scope.myModel` to an array.

Comment: Well, i can't do that exactly because i have an array for each element of my array...meh.  This is because i'm using a particular data-structure from C#: Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Comment: Can you [update this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5Lrahyz/) with some data that mimic the structure you have?

Answer (score 0):

I would prep data before you use it in ng-repeat you can do this by grabbing the object keys, sorting them and using them to create a new sorted object.
Here is a working plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/CktRzgo7je40gBxXILKi?p=info

```
//js
  $scope.myModel =  {
    "10/14/2015 1:30:00 PM" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
    "10/14/2015 9:30:00 AM" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
    "10/5/2015 9:30:00 PM" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
    "10/6/2015 9:30:00 PM" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
    "10/7/2015 9:30:00 PM" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
  };

  $scope.mySortedModel = {};

  $scope.myModelSortedKeysAsc = Object.keys($scope.myModel).sort(function(a,b){
       return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
  });

   $scope.myModelSortedKeysAsc.forEach(function(el){

       $scope.mySortedModel[el] = $scope.myModel[el];
   });

   // html 

   <div  ng-repeat="(key, value) in mySortedModel">
      {{key}--{{value}}
  </div>
```